# How to color the line graph according to conditions in a plot?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, plot

I try to find the solution for plot of the data
I have a graph of trajectory according to time(x) and kilometers(y) and i need to mark with different colours where the availability parameter from dataframe is 0 or 100

I try this but i have completly different result that i expected

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Read file, using ; as delimiter
filename = "H:\\run_linux\\river_km_calculations\\route2_8_07_23_07\\true_route2_8_07_23_07_test.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter=';', parse_dates=['datetime']) #dtype={'lon_deg':'float', 'lat_deg':'float'})


df = df[189940:]

df.set_index('datetime', inplace=False)
plt.plot( df['datetime'], df['river_km'])
plt.show()

connection = 100
noconection = 0


def conditions(s):
    if (s['age_gps_data'] <= 1.5) or (s['age_gps_data'] >=0.5 ):
        return 100
    else:
        return 0

df['availability'] = df.apply(conditions, axis=1)

internet = np.ma.masked_where(df.availability == connection, df.availability)
nointernet = np.ma.masked_where((df.availability == noconection) , df.availability)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df.river_km, internet, df.river_km, nointernet)
plt.show()
```

How I can mark on a plot with different colours where availability is 0 and where is 100 and where is no value of these parameter?
What I want to achieve should looks like this:
[image]

Comment: so you want to color-code your graph based on conneciton status? then you could consider using `scatter`, with a color vector as keyword argument, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43090817/matplotlib-scatter-plot-change-color-based-on-value-on-list)